# Calculations of zero mean normalized cross-correlation in dm-script

Tags: dm-script

Now I'm trying to make a dm-script for calculation of zero mean normalized cross-correlation (ZNCC) between two images. In the calculation of ZNCC, it is known that usages of FFT and integral image are quite efficient scheme. So I have made a following test script to calculate a integral image. However, this calculation is not sufficiently fast for typical image sizes of camera images, in my sence. Do you have any good idea to improve the calculation speed of integral image calculations? Alternatively, does anyone know some scripts for fast ZNCC calculations? Can I pick your brains?

```
Image integralImg( Image &inputImg ){
    Number nx, ny
    Number iu, iv, tmpval, fval, integ_pre1, integ_pre2, integ_pre3
    Image integImg := inputImg.ImageClone()
    integImg.SetName("Integral Image of " + inputImg.GetName())
    inputImg.GetSize(nx, ny)
    fval = inputImg.GetPixel(0, 0)
    integImg.SetPixel(0, 0, fval)
    FOR(iu = 1 ; iu < nx ; iu++){
        fval = inputImg.GetPixel(iu, 0)
        integ_pre1 = integImg.GetPixel(iu - 1, 0)
        integImg.SetPixel(iu, 0, fval + integ_pre1)
    }
    FOR(iv = 1 ; iv < ny ; iv++){
        fval = inputImg.GetPixel(0, iv)
        integ_pre2 = integImg.GetPixel(0, iv - 1)
        integImg.SetPixel(0, iv, fval + integ_pre2)
    }
    FOR(iv = 1 ; iv < ny ; iv++){
        FOR(iu = 1 ; iu < nx ; iu++){
            fval = inputImg.GetPixel(iu,iv)
            integ_pre1 = integImg.GetPixel(iu - 1, iv)
            integ_pre2 = integImg.GetPixel(iu, iv - 1)
            integ_pre3 = integImg.GetPixel(iu - 1, iv - 1)
            integImg.SetPixel(iu, iv, fval + integ_pre1 + integ_pre2 - integ_pre3)
        }
    }
    Return integImg
}
//
Number nx = 1024
Number ny = 1024
Image IMG := RealImage("test",4,nx,ny)
IMG = Random()
//
Image intIMG
intIMG := integralImg( IMG )
intIMG.ShowImage()
```

Comment: Any 'for-loop' type script with single-pixel-adressing over an image will be tremendously (unfeasible) slow in the purely interpreted script language, and there is little you can do about it. The only "hope" is to build up the algorithm using image-expressions and commands which act on arrays (images) direclty. Typically, using 'icol', 'irow' and the like gives you a speed boost. But still not to the level of compiled code and using those commands. Correlations are also typically computed in FourierSpace, so you might want to look into the 'FFT' commands. There is also a crossCorrelation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not just use the command

`RealImage CrossCorrelate( RealImage source1, RealImage source2 )`  ?

If not, can you explain to me, what exactly is different to a ZNCC?
( Note, that you can easily shift each source image to a mean value of zero by `img -= mean(img)`)

Comment: Thank you very much for your immediate responses. As you have commented above, the standard function “CrossCorrelate” can calculate a zero-mean normalized cross-correlation (ZNCC) image rather than a “standard” un-normalized cross-correlation. I’m sorry. I misunderstood the function of “CrossCorrelate”.

Comment: However, this ZNCC image is the cross-correlation map between “whole” patterns of two images with same image sizes. On the other hand, my objective is to calculate a ZNCC image between two images with different image sizes. In this case, a reference template image has smaller image size than an object image. So, ZNCC is calculated between a small refence image and “partial” area of a large object image.

Comment: Thus, in simplest implementation, ZNCC calculations between all many positions of partial images in the object image and one small reference image should be carried out sequentially. But, in this kind of implementation, the calculation speed is quite slow. For example, a faster algorithm is shown in [1]. In this scheme, calculations of “integral images” as shown in an example code which I have posted firstly, are required. But this kind of “for-loop” type script is quite slow as you pointed out. 

[1]: http://i81pc23.itec.uni-karlsruhe.de/Publikationen/SPIE01_BriechleHanebeck_CrossCorr.pdf

Comment: @kachigusa I might be wrong, but if you're after a "template matching" type of fit, then I think you can embed your search-pattern in a 0-padded image of same size as your source and use the regular-crosscorralation. Even if that means the CC computed over a larger array, it uses the "compiled" code and should be much faster!

Comment: Thank you so much for you nice suggestion. Now I trying to write a templete matching code based on a  ZNCC-"like" map according to your suggesting of 0-padded images and their FFT treatment. Although that is not perfectly working well at this time, things will work out probably. Thanks again for your many helpful comments.